# Unable to download updates from extensions.gnome.org

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and get the below message when I open the Ubuntu software app. My computer is updated to the latest version. How to solve this.

[image]

Comment: It's probably a temporary connectivity issue with extensions.gnome.org.

Comment: I'm having this issue on Ubuntu 18.10. This is my personal laptop so no proxy involved.

Comment: @yahavi Does the problem still there? You might like to ask a new question.

Comment: @Kulfy the answer of Bewarb solved my problem

Comment: This only seems to happen on first start up when there is no internet connection.

Comment: same as @holmberd, initial startup issue.  Added network connection, rebooted and no more issue.

Answer (score 18):

I was having same problem, no Internet issue was there. I did following -

Installed gnome-shell-extensions again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-shell-extensions/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

I reinstalled gnome shell extension in firefox, and after some time, it started working. After that Ubuntu Software Manager showed no such error.

Comment: On 19.04 I get a "E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: You don't need the PPA on 19.04. Just install it directly.

Comment: Hello @BEWARB does your solution work for ubuntu 19.10 as well?

Comment: I get: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~gnome-shell-extensions/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~gnome-shell-extensions' user or team does not exist.`