# Unable to Download Updates / Cannot resolve hostname?

Tags: networking, dns, 19.04

When launching Software, I'm getting errors stating:

```
Unable to download updates: failed to refresh cache: E: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease is not (yet) available. (Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com')
```

And

```
Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org": failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Cannot resolve hostname
```

And

```
Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed to download https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/ratings: Cannot resolve hostname
```

I used to run PiHole and custom DNS but I don't anymore, it's all back to normal now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: When you go to sourceforge.net/speedtest does it resolve & what are your speeds?

Are you able to ping http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb or one of the other sites contained in that error?

Comment: @curios Speedtest.net results: Pings reaction time 14ms, Download 21.64MBPS, Upload 5.06MBPS. I tried `ping http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb` and was told `Name or service not known.`

Comment: Sounds like an 18.04 problem caused by a missing libnss-resolve package, but that does not exist in 19.04.  Does your /etc/nsswitch.conf file have a line like:hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, here is what it says `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns` (direct copy/paste)

Comment: I don't run a full 19.04, so maybe I'm wrong about the libnss-resolve not being available.  Try sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve and see what happens.  If nothing, you can edit your hosts line to have the  "resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]" befoer the dns -- That's really all I know that installing the package does anyway.

Comment: @ubfan1 I ran the line but it's still happening :( What should I change the line to? `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns` ? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @ubfan1 So I fixed this by disabling some repos and re-running! Slowly getting better at Linux, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Researching found this previous question which seems similar to yours:

[Unable to download updates from extensions.gnome.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032770/unable-to-download-updates-from-extensions-gnome-org)

The answer in that case was to:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-shell-extensions/ppa
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions

For starters, though, I'd go with a simple:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

and see if that resolves.

Comment: I tried the two commands in the first line and got this back, `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.` :(

Comment: @LeslieLemon did you solve you problem? because it seems we are the only ones on the whole internet to have this problem...

Comment: @Stephane No, it is a recurring thing. It seems like it keeps reverting to selecting a repo that isn't good anymore. But if I disselect the repo and try again, it works. So it must be a dependency of some program I have.

Comment: I solved it at my side. I edited my repositories setup. I realised afterwards that with Stader (a snap package I believe)I can easily access the list of repositories (the 10th menu on the left toolbar).

Comment: @Stephane I have a similar problem. Could you elaborate on how you solve this? I believe there are many people encounter this.