# Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed to download https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/ratings: Service Unavailable: <html>

Tags: software-center, budgie

I just installed Ubuntu Budgie 19.04

And when I am trying to work in Software Center it says -

```
Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed to download https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/ratings: Service Unavailable: <html>
```

[image]

Comment: • Was this a transient issue, just some third party server down? • Could you ping odrs.gnome.org at the time? • There are some hits when searching the internet for "Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed". • A related question is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032770/unable-to-download-updates-from-extensions-gnome-org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work for me

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

maybe can try with another ideas from [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-fixes/) site

Comment: Uninstalling gnome-software in 19.10 also removes ubuntu-software, so
"sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install ubuntu-software"
is better