# Software center doesn't have any proper icons and outputs a lot of errors when going into the update section

Tags: gnome, software-center, apparmor

I'm a complete newbie that installed Ubuntu a couple of days ago and ran into some issues.

The software center looks like this:
[image]

And when I enter the updates section, the following errors are outputted:

```
Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed to download https://gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/-rating: Connection terminated unexpectedly
```

The following error also appears:

[image]

(sorry, but didn't find a way to copy that text and I'm too lazy to type it out)

However, if I can find the app, the downloads seem to work fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to download updates from "odrs.gnome.org": failed to download https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/ratings: Service Unavailable: <html>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144539/unable-to-download-updates-from-odrs-gnome-org-failed-to-download-https-odr)

Comment: This linked question has answers that recommend you to reinstall `gnome-software`, which may solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention but I've already tried all of the possibilities like reinstalling the software center and reinstalling gnome-software but the issue didn't go away. The software center was bugged from the start.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the `snap-store`?

Comment: Turns out it was the snap store that was somehow disguised as the software center because after I deleted and reinstalled snap store, I could find 2 icons: snap store and software, but the problems are still there and the new interface of the snap store isn’t much different from the old one - still bugged